# Scroll to top of an element from a button inside that element

Tags: jquery, scroll

How would I accomplish scrolling to the top of an element from a button that resides inside that element? I have [found this function](http://www.dconnell.co.uk/blog/index.php/2012/03/12/scroll-to-any-element-using-jquery/) below, but am not sure about how to accomplish capturing the button's parent element - I do not want to hard-code all buttons and all elements with IDs.

Thanks for some advice!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollBack(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
    time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 1000;
    verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
    element = $(selector);
    offset = element.offset();
    offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, time);
}

$('.scrollback').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
    scrollBack($(this).parent(), 500, -96);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean the function should be called with the direct parent of the clicked button? Something like: `scrollToElement($(this).parent());`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed it. I amend the snippet above with your correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.scrollback').click(function() {
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $('.scrollback').parent().offset().top},'slow');
}
```

That should work.